# Does io.lines() stream or slurp the file?

Tags: lua

For algorithms that support line by line processing, lua documentation suggests that using `io.lines()` is more efficient than `io:read("*line")` in a while loop.

> The call io.read("*line") returns the next line from the current input
>   file, without the newline character. (...) However, to iterate on a
>   whole file line by line, we do better to use the io.lines iterator. ([21.1 – The Simple I/O Model](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html))

I can imagine three possible reasons that the `io.lines()` call is preferred.

1. The iterator is more efficient than the while loop
2. The file reading is handled more efficiently
3. It's easier to read/maintain the code

The lua documentation also promotes slurping files

> (Y)ou should always consider the alternative of reading the whole file
>   with option "*all" from io.read and then using gfind to break it up ([21.1 – The Simple I/O Model](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html))

**Hypothesis**: `io:read("*line")` streams the file. If slurping is more efficient in lua, and `io.lines()` slurps the file, then `io.lines()` might be more efficient for that reason.

However, [the unofficial Lua FAQ](http://www.luafaq.org/#T2.3) has the following to say about `io.lines()`

> Note that it is an iterator, this does not bring
>   the whole file into memory initially.

This suggests streaming instead of slurping.

**TLDR** Does `io.lines()` ever hold the whole file in memory or does it only hold one line in memory at a time? Is its memory usage different than `io:read("*line")` in a while loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`io.lines()` does not hold the whole file in memory: it reads the file one line at a time, not the whole file at once. For that, use `io.read("*all")`.

Comment: To clarify, does io.lines ever hold the whole file in memory? I know that I only have access to one line at a time, but is its memory usage different than io:read("*line") in a while loop?